# Clone custom structs of concrete type as trait objects

Tags: rust, wrapper, trait-objects

Using `Rc`, I can cast an `Rc` of a concrete type to a trait object:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

trait Foo {}

impl Foo for usize {}

fn main() {
    let x: Rc<usize> = Rc::new(1);
    let y: Rc<dyn Foo> = x.clone();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f4d43eff2c0f03eb6e866cd3ceef20fb).

If I define a wrapper for an `Rc` without the `Sized` bound, I can also use trait objects:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

trait Foo {}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Wrapper<T: ?Sized>(Rc<T>);


impl Foo for usize {}

fn main() {
    let x: Wrapper<dyn Foo> = Wrapper(Rc::new(1));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0ec2d3dab21b2bed109a29f35083a6ba).

However, I cannot clone a wrapper of a concrete type as a trait object:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

trait Foo {}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Wrapper<T: ?Sized>(Rc<T>);


impl Foo for usize {}

fn main() {
    let x: Wrapper<usize> = Wrapper(Rc::new(1));
    let y: Wrapper<dyn Foo> = x.clone(); // this does not compile
}
```

The compiler complains with the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:13:31
   |
13 |     let y: Wrapper<dyn Foo> = x.clone();
   |            ----------------   ^^^^^^^^^ expected trait object `dyn Foo`, found `usize`
   |            |
   |            expected due to this
   |
   = note: expected struct `Wrapper<dyn Foo>`
              found struct `Wrapper<usize>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=aaee4b781ceb651ddbdcf3562d83bbb0).

I'm a little bit confused, as I don't understand why the third example does not work. Can anyone help me to get the third example working? what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your own version of coercion to an unsized type by implementing [`CoerceUnsized`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.CoerceUnsized.html) for your `Wrapper`:

```rust
#![feature(unsize, coerce_unsized)]
use std::ops::CoerceUnsized;
use std::marker::Unsize;
impl<U: ?Sized, T: Unsize<U>> CoerceUnsized<Wrapper<U>> for Wrapper<T> {}
```

then the syntax you used initially does compile

```rust
fn main() {
    let x: Wrapper<usize> = Wrapper(Rc::new(1));
    let y: Wrapper<dyn Foo> = x.clone();
}
```

But since you did not include that implementation the compiler doesn't know that your type can be unsized.

Note: Right now that requires the features `unsize` and `coerce_unsized` though so you have to compile with a nightly compiler.

Comment: I guess that the implementation of that trait will look like my answer, right?

Comment: No, `CoerceUnsized` has no methods, coercion is automatically implemented by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

This other example works:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

trait Foo {}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Wrapper<T: ?Sized>(Rc<T>);


impl Foo for usize {}

fn main() {
    let x: Wrapper<usize> = Wrapper(Rc::new(1));
    let y: Wrapper<dyn Foo> = Wrapper(x.0.clone()); // clone inner Rc
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=686881ef433042fcb46a47491f2272c0).

While it is enough for me, I think that it has too much boilerplate code. Other suggestions are welcome.